# Cassandra hard vs soft delete

Tags: cassandra

I have multiple tables that I want to keep their deleted data.

I thought of two options to achieve that:

1. Create new table called deleted_x and when deleting from x, immediatly insert to deleted_x.

   *Advantage* : querying from only one table.

   *Disadvantages* :

   - Do insert for each delete
   - When the original table structure changes, I will have to change the deleted table too.
2. Have a column called `is_deleted` and put it in the partition key in each of these tables and set it to true when deleting a row.

   *Advantage* : One table structure

   *Disadvantage* : mention `is_deleted` in all queries from table

Are there any performence considerations I should think of additionally?
Which way is the better way?

Comment: Why just not keep the data and just use a `deleted` flag for the same table?

Comment: This is exactly the scenario explained in option#2. The problem is having to query always by this `deleted` flag and that means put it in the primary key or be exposed to developers mistakes who can query without it by having secondary index

Answer (score 2):

Option #1 is awkward, but it's probably the right way to do things in Cassandra. You could issue the two mutations (one DELETE, and one INSERT) in a single batch, and guarantee that both are written.

Option #2 isn't really as easy as you may expect if you're coming from a relational background, because adding an `is_deleted` column to a table in Cassandra and expecting to be able to query against it isn't trivial. The primary reason is that Cassandra performs significantly better when querying against the primary key (partition key(s) + optional clustering key(s) than secondary indexes. Therefore, for maximum performance, you'd need to model this as a clustering key - doing so then prohibits you from simply issuing an update - you'd need to delete + insert, anyway.

Option #2 becomes somewhat more viable in 3.0+ with Materialized Views - if you're looking at Cassandra 3.0+, it may be worth considering.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand why option#1 is better. Are there any performence issues? because in option#1 I will have to maintain the table structure in another table. Do you have experience in both ways?

Comment: Could you elaborate on creating a materialized view? If I want the materialized view to contain all the non-deleted items, then the `is_deleted` column still needs to be part of the primary key as part of the requirements for the materialized view.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any performence considerations I should think of additionally?

You will effectively double the write load and storage size for your cluster by inserting your data twice. This includes compactions, repairs, bootstrapping new nodes and backups.

> Which way is the better way?

Let me suggest a 3rd option instead.

1. Create table `all_data` that contains each row and will never be deleted from
2. Create table `active_data` using the same partition key. This table will only contain non-deleted rows (**Edit:** but not any data at all, just the key!).
3. Check if key is in `active_data` before reading from `all_data` will allow you to only read non-deleted rows

Comment: This is usually considered an anti pattern in Cassandra. Writing data twice is considered acceptable.